# R matrix creating

Tags: r, matrix

Hi there I have a quick question about R.
I have three statements:

```
    n=187
    a <- MatrixA[ (1):(4*n), c('x1','y') ]
    b <- MatrixA[ (1):(4*n), c('y') ]
```

where Matrix A is a 1250 x 2 matrix with the first column labeled 'x1' and the second column labeled 'y'.

I run the command and a becomes a 748 x 2 **matrix** however b is a **value** (it says int[1:748] blablabla).
Why is this? I am confused: these statements are almost identical.

My end goal is to create b as a 748 x 1 matrix with the values of column 'y'.
Any help appreciated and thank you for reading!!

my about Rstudio: Version 0.99.893 – © 2009-2016 RStudio, Inc.
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/601.4.4 (KHTML, like Gecko)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When subsetting, R will simplify the output if possible. For example, if you only pick a single column of a matrix, by default it will be coerced to a vector. See [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) for details.

A quick solution is to do:

```
b <- MatrixA[ (1):(4*n), c('y'), drop=FALSE]
```

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. Thank you for you help! It was much appreciated. I can't imagine for my life why R thought this was a good design. Seems totally unintuitive!!